# Are infinite Dedekind-finite cardinals “cancellable” in $\sf ZF$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $\mathfrak p$ be infinite Dedekind-finite. It is known that, in $\sf ZF$, for any non-zero finite ordinal $n$, we have $|n \cdot |A|| = |n \cdot |B|| \implies |A| = |B|$ for any sets $A$ and $B$. Motivated by this, is it true that $\mathfrak p \cdot |A| = \mathfrak p \cdot |B| \implies |A| = |B|$ for any sets $A$ and $B$, where $\mathfrak p$ is arbitrary and as above? Or at least is there a model of $\sf ZF$ with a Dedekind-finite set in it which satisfies this property?

Note that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then this holds, as (Dedekind-)finite union of Dedekind-finite sets is Dedekind-finite.

This question arised because of the fact that, in $\sf ZFC$, all “cancellable” sets are finite, this made me wonder if there are sets in $\sf ZF$ which are “cancellable” but not finite, or at least if there is a spesific set in a spesific model of $\sf ZF$ with this property, thank you.

Comment: Does the "$\mathfrak p$ is arbitrary" supposed to be "arbitrary Dedekind finite"?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but note that if the class of Dedekind finite cardinals is linearly ordered, then it's form a model of PA, so it is consistent that $\mathfrak p \cdot |A| = \mathfrak p \cdot |B| \implies |A| = |B|$ for $|A|,|B|,\mathfrak p$ Dedekind finite

Comment: @ℋolo Yes, I tried to mean that by saying “…where $\mathfrak p$ is arbitrary and as above?”.

Comment: @ℋolo That’s a good observation, at least it allows us to lift the result in my question from finite $A$ and $B$ to Dedekind-finite $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @ℋolo And [they *can* be linearly ordered](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484381900176)!

Comment: @NoahSchweber That paper is my number 1 paper in terms of "want to understand" :),  although it being 60 pages long doesn't help

Comment: @ℋolo: Write me an email. Preferably yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

(This is a partial answer), I am not sure about arbitrary sets $A,B$, but I can give the following $2$ points:

1. If $\mathfrak p$ is a non-zero Dedekind finite cardinal, and $A,B$ are well orderable, then $\mathfrak p \cdot |A| = \mathfrak p \cdot |B| \implies |A| = |B|$.
2. It is consistent that $\mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak n = \mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak m \implies \mathfrak n = \mathfrak m$ for all non-zero Dedekind finite $\mathfrak{p,n,m}$.

---

Proof of (1):

Let $\mathfrak p=|P|$ be non-zero Dedekind finite and $|A|<|B|$ aleph numbers, we will show that $\mathfrak p \cdot |A| < \mathfrak p \cdot |B|$.

It is clear that $\mathfrak p \cdot |A| ≤ \mathfrak p \cdot |B|$, assume that they are equal and let $f:A×P→B×P$ be a bijection, we will recursively define an injection from $ω$ to $P$.

Assume that $g_k:k\to P$ is injective, define on $B\times f_k''k$ the following (modified) lexicographic order: $(a,g_k(i))<'(b,g_k(j))⇔i<j∨(i=j∧a<b)$.

This is a well ordering, and because $g_k''k$ is finite, $|A\times g_k''k|<'|B\times g_k''k|$.

Let $(a,g_k(i))$ be the $<'$-first element such that $f((a,g_k(i)))=(b,p)∈P×B\setminus P×g_k''k$, and define $g_{k+1}:k+1→P$ as $g_k\cup\{(k, p)\}$.

Then $\bigcup_{i\in\omega}g_i$ is an injection from $ω$ to $P$, contradiction.

---

"Proof" of (2):

First note that it is consistent that the class of Dedekind finite cardinals is linearly ordered ([as is done in this paper by Gershon Sageev](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484381900176), mentioned by Noah).

Then we take the result of Ellentuck that if the class of Dedekind finite cardinals is linearly ordered, then that class form a model of Peano Axioms.

This theorem supposedly appears in his paper [The Universal Properties of Dedekind Finite Cardinals](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970643)
 But I couldn't find it there, as well as in his book [The Theory of Dedekind Finite Cardinals](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/The_Theory_of_Dedekind_Finite_Cardinals.html?id=RmZKAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)
 that I couldn't find anywhere.

I did find the proof of the theorem in his paper [A Model of Arithmetic](https://logic-library.berkeley.edu//catalog/detail/739), but I couldn't find any **Legal** prints of this paper.

---

Addon: As [@user14111](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1086185/user14111) correctly said, we don't actually need a full model of Peano Axioms, we just need to note the following fact

3. If $\mathfrak{p,n,m}$ are Dedekind finite such that $\mathfrak n < \mathfrak m$, then $\mathfrak p\cdot \mathfrak n < \mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak m$

Then if the Dedekind finite cardinals are linearly ordered, we get $\mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak n = \mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak m \implies \mathfrak n = \mathfrak m$.

To prove (3), let's note (given $P,N,M$ sets of those cardinality) that $P×N⊊P×M$ and that product of Dedekind finite cardinals is Dedekind finite, hence we get $\mathfrak p\cdot \mathfrak n < \mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak m$.

---

Addon 2: After reading a little bit more of "The Universal Properties of Dedekind Finite Cardinals", it appears to be that Ellentuck actually proved that with ACF (families of non-empty finite sets have a choice function) we have $\mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak n = \mathfrak p \cdot \mathfrak m \implies \mathfrak n = \mathfrak m$ for all non-zero Dedkind finite $\mathfrak{p,n,m}$, even without linear order.

Gershon Sageev claims that Ellentuck proved the above without the use ACF, but I couldn't find such proof

Comment: I want to wait and see if there will be a full answer, other than that, this is a very good answer!

Comment: @user14111 You are correct, I added it into the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Tan I added another section I found, sadly still not a complete answer

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I will check it out.